# Ext.data.JsonP.request Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: extjs

I have used Ext.data.JsonP.request and get 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <'
here is a part of code:

```
 Ext.data.JsonP.request({
           url: url,
           scope: this,
           callback: function(data) {

           },
```

How can I parse it?

Comment: Could you use browser dev tool(press F12 in chrome/firefox) to check what is the response from server? I met this error before because the server encounter 500 error and reply a html page

Comment: Yes it's reply a html page

Comment: What data do you expect?

Comment: Actually, I want to check 'X-Frame-Options' header for that url

Answer (score 0):

Your request fails because the response data is not valid JavaScript.
Also: A JSONP request can never be used to read the response headers.

This is because a JSONP request isn't actually a new type of Request, but instead it's just a script tag inserted on-the-fly into the head part of the DOM.

In order to get the headers of an HTTP resource, best use a standard Ext.AJAX request and make sure the resource you want to access will send proper `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers.
For more details about this look up [Cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) and the [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).